# What is the difference (or relationship) between geometric length and arithmetic numbers?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, arithmetic, math-history

In Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* there was a phrase like, "Ancient Greeks did not understand the difference (or relationship) between geometric length and arithmetic numbers." What is this difference (or relationship)? Could this misunderstanding be the main reason behind the Zeno's paradoxes?

Comment: I think to get an answer to this you will need someone with a good knowledge of the history of mathematics, so I have added the appropriate tag.  Feel free to remove it if you don't agree.

Comment: Arithmetic numbers can be used to express geometric lengths? That is the first thing that pops up into my mind. Don't know whether that is correct and that it is what they mean.

Comment: @David No I agree thank you.

Comment: Maybe they didn't saw that that numbers used in geometry where actually the same as numbers used in other applications ("What the hell has counting apples to do with measuring things in geometry?"); that numbers have some underlying basis (as explained in arithmetics) , and they didn't see that connection.

Comment: My understanding is they never really abstracted numbers away from lengths; all of their proofs regarding facts about numbers were geometric in nature.

Comment: I think the comment of @Pedro has some merit. Notably, mathematical formulae were often described using geometry: "The area of a square of side $a+b$ is the combined area of two squares, one of side $a$ and one of side $b$, plus twice the area of the rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$." $\Leftrightarrow$ $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$

Comment: You might try the http://hsm.stackexchange.com site as well.

Comment: @Pedro the comment of Dustan has a point.

Comment: @i.ozturk I agree.

Comment: @Pedro But still I can't figure the difference. Thank you for finding this question also interesting.

Comment: Maybe the difference between the two that he means is that one is more fundamental/abstract, while the other is in fact making use of the other one. And they thought it was all one sort of messy thing they couldn't understand (and because of that their proofs were geometric in nature as Dustan says; it was all too messy so they didn't find the connection). But later on, people found the relation and similarities between those two things (as Dustin says: they never abstracted numbers away from lengths), which means they didn't saw that numbers can be abstracted.

Comment: I do not agree with Abbott's comment; see this [post](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2/irrationality-of-the-square-root-of-2) : In ancient Greek math the only numbers are the *natural* ones and they must be distinguished from *magnitudes* : a segment, a square, ... which are "measured by" numbers. Thus, they "perceive a clear difference between a number and a geometrical magnitude.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I can't remember the exact phrase of Abbott so it may not be the difference but the relationship. I will edit the question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA As far as I understand, since they have only rational numbers they are confused with the irrational lengths and they seperated the notion of numbers and lengths. Actually the lengths are measured by numbers and this is the relationship between them. So this was their misunderstanding. You can post your comment as an answer if you want. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preliminaries**

There have been two simple constructions in geometry known since ancient times. (1) Halving a line segment. (2) Copying a line segment from here to there (onto a straight line from a given point). Based on these two operations one can compare line segments; one can say, for instance that $AB$ is shorter or longer than $CD$. Claiming that two segments are of equal length is a much harder problem!

**The first Chapter**

Given a segment of "unit length" (this is just a name for now) one can use the two constructions above to "measure" the length of a given segment with arbitrary precision but not necessarily with complete precision. Already the ancient Greeks discovered that the hypotenuse of a right triangle cannot be measured with complete precision in terms of the legs of the same triangle. For them the distribution of the points on a straight line must have seemed to be too sparse for they could not find the exact end points of the hypotenuse of certain triangles.

For the Greeks only the rational numbers were "rational". So, the length of the hypotenuse mentioned above must have been a mystery for them -- if not a mystery then at least something "irrational". But the ancient Greeks were not able to overcome this intellectual challenge.

**The Second Chapter**

Already Archimedes observed that there was another problem with the concept length. He nailed down the axiom (named after him) that there were no segments of infinitesimal length. As he put it: "Given a line segment $AB$ shorter than another line segment $CD$ there is a natural $n$ such that copying the segment $AB$ $n$ times onto a straight line consecutively one can create a segment longer than $CD$. Archimedes must have noticed that his axiom could not be deduced from the Euclidean axioms.

So Archimedes had to axiomatically exclude the potential point sets consisting of points situated so close to each other such that the segment cannot be used as a measuring rod.

**The Third Chapter**

We have seen so far that the Euclidean points on an Euclidean straight line are not dense enough and at the same time their distribution can be (locally) too dense. At least, this is how I imagine the mind set of the pre-Archimedian and post-Euclidean Greek geometer.

**The Fourth Chapter**

It took more than two thousand years in geometry to arrive to the Dedekind axiom that regulated the density of the points on a straight line so it don't be neither too dense nor too sparse.

**The Fifth Chapter**

The development of the real numbers is very similar to the development of the ordering and regulating the density of the points of a straight line. The concept of an ordered field does not grab the concept of the real number without the Dedekind axiom, the density regulator.

Today it is easy to see the isometry between the Euclidean line and the set of Reals. Be aware that the common central concepts of the geometry of the straight line and the topology of the reals are: ordering and regulating density. (For instance: Non standard analysis comes from changing the density regulations.)

**Epilogue**
The concept of real numbers and the concept of length in geometry are two notions with a parallel development process. We can see clearly the differences and the similarities.

Comment: This is a gloss on the conventional story, which has (in my opinion) been convincingly refuted over the past 50 years. Some points: Archimedes is unlikely to have invented his axiom, as he attributes it to Eudoxus (if I remember correctly - check for yourself). There was probably no "crisis" because of irrational lengths - see the relevant chapter in Fowler's *Plato's Academy*. The Greeks had a definition of 'real numbers' exceedingly similar to Dedekind's, so similar in fact because he modelled his on theirs.

Moral of the story: don't believe all you read.

Comment: @MariusKempe: Thank you! I will read the book you suggested. It may happen that I change my views again...

Comment: You're welcome! The relevant section is 8.3 in Fowler's *The Mathematics of Plato's Academy*. I also recommend [this article](http://www.lrb.co.uk.ezphost.dur.ac.uk/v29/n04/mf-burnyeat/other-lives) on the myth of Pythagoras. For Eudoxus' (?) axiom, see p. 186 of van der Waerden's *Science Awakening*.

Comment: @MariusKempe: I've just purchased the book on Amazon.co.uk. So, I have to wait a little. Then I would be glad to share my new ideas...

Comment: I hope you enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a line segment of any length, and designate it as having length  one, the Greeks believed it's always possible to precisely measure geometric lengths using this unit length. For example, to measure a length of 1.2, you can (after some trial and error) divide the unit length into five subunits of length 0.2, so that 1.2 is comprised of exactly 6 such subunits. This implicitly assumes that lengths can be expressed as the ratios of two numbers, i.e. lengths (corresponding to real numbers) are rational, thus it is impossible to measure irrational lengths like $\sqrt 2$ because no unit can fit evenly into these lengths. As Abbott wrote, the Greeks "were forced to accept that number was a strictly weaker notion than length". In modern terms, $\mathbb{Q} \subset\mathbb{R}$.

Citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Ancient_Greece): "The Pythagorean method ... claimed that there must be some sufficiently small, indivisible unit that could fit evenly into one of these lengths as well as the other. However, Hippasus, in the 5th century BC, was able to deduce that there was in fact no common unit of measure, and that the assertion of such an existence was in fact a contradiction. He did this by demonstrating that if the hypotenuse of an isosceles right triangle was indeed commensurable with a leg, then one of those lengths measured in that unit of measure must be both odd and even, which is impossible."